# Why does the iPhone simulator show "Simulator in use" when I try to run my project and the simulator is not in use?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

For some reason, when I try to run my projects in Xcode I get the message "simulator in use", but The simulator is not in use. I tried restarting Xcode and resetting simulator, but I still get the same message.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting?

Comment: The Simulator runs as a seperate process. Have you tried to kill it instead of xcode?

Comment: yes. i have tried what you suggested

Comment: Not much you can do but restart your computer at this point..

Comment: i have tried this too but the problem is still the same, even after launching for the first time the simulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is no longer happening. It had to do with the beta version of XCode.